# Import SQL dump into PostgreSQL database

Tags: database, postgresql

We are switching hosts and the old one provided a SQL dump of the PostgreSQL database of our site.

Now, I'm trying to set this up on a local WAMP server to test this.

The only problem is that I don't have an idea how to import this database in the PostgreSQL 9 that I have set up.

I tried pgAdmin III but I can't seem to find an 'import' function. So I just opened the SQL editor and pasted the contents of the dump there and executed it, it creates the tables but it keeps giving me errors when it tries to put the data in it.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "t"
LINE 474: t 2011-05-24 16:45:01.768633 2011-05-24 16:45:01.768633 view...

The lines:
COPY tb_abilities (active, creation, modtime, id, lang, title, description) FROM stdin;
t   2011-05-24 16:45:01.768633  2011-05-24 16:45:01.768633  view    nl ...
```

I've also tried to do this with the command prompt but I can't find the command that I need.

If I do

```
psql mydatabase < C:/database/db-backup.sql;
```

I get the error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
LINE 1: psql mydatabase < C:/database/db-backu...
        ^
```

What's the best way to import the database?

Comment: I had a similar error to your first one: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "t"`. It turned out that I had only imported a partial schema and thus a `CREATE TABLE` statement earlier in the script had failed. Look through the full output of the import to find it.

Answer (score 1031, accepted):

```
psql --username=<db_user_name> databasename < data_base_dump
```

That's the command you are looking for.

Beware: `databasename` must be created before importing.
Have a look at the [PostgreSQL Docs Chapter 23. Backup and Restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE).

Comment: I've tried that psql mydatabase < C:\database\db-backup.sql but i get the error Invalid command \database. I also tried with " " around it.

Comment: Have you tried cd'ing to C:\database und calling psql mydatabase < db-backup.sql?

Comment: @Dazz You have to do this command from your command prompt (Start -> Run -> cmd) , not from the postgres prompt.

Comment: if i run it from cmd i get 'The '<' operator is reserved for future use.'

Comment: @Dazz:You could use `-f` switch (or `--file`) too

Comment: Can't be. The error you are quoting is from PowerShell, not from the Windows Command Prompt. You are typing the command into the wrong shell.

Comment: Yes PowerShell but that works to. I got it working: psql -f sdb-backup.sql mydatabase;

Comment: this document is a good reference for messing around with posgres databases http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html

"pg_dump dbname > outfile"
"gunzip -c filename.gz | psql dbname"

Comment: psql --username=postgres databasename < data_base_dump.sql

Comment: ownerit says peer authentication failed. even if i input correct password :(

Comment: this solution worked for me, but only after i dropped my database (using `rake db:drop`) and created it (using `rake db:create`) first (as @jacob mentions above). ran a migration afterwards as well then good to go.

Comment: @user151496 You have to change your current user. If you use peer authentication, Postgre will assume that your user is your OS current user. Export a PGUSER env var (set it as your preferred db username) and setup a ~/.pgpass file as well. That should sort your problems.

Comment: for finding current database, use `select current_database();` in psql

Comment: getting this 
"The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump.
Use the pg_restore command-line client to restore this dump to a database."

Comment: If you are importing a huge dump, don't forget to wrap the dump in BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT to keep psql from committing after every row.

Comment: Hi, is possible exclude a specific table in existing 'data_base_dump' file

Comment: Shorter form: `psql -U postgres databasename < data_base_dump.sql`

Answer (score 548):

Here is the command you are looking for.

```
psql -h hostname -d databasename -U username -f file.sql
```

Comment: Good, but better append also the "-L logfile.log" param to log the output on file.

Comment: getting this 
"The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump.
Use the pg_restore command-line client to restore this dump to a database."

Comment: You can also: `pg_restore -h hostname -d dbname -U username filename.sql`

Comment: How to deal with `ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint`? I would like `psql` to ignore when there's a duplicate key

Comment: In my case I am running postgres on different port, so I have to add -p <portno.> along with the above command

Comment: what is I want to replace the existing table while loading like this? will it succeed?

Answer (score 164):

I believe that you want to run in psql:

```
\i C:/database/db-backup.sql
```

Comment: Had to use this because Emacs' eshell doesn't support input redirection. Thanks.

Comment: Be sure to change to the database first with \c <database_name>

Comment: use \ir if you want to give it a relative path.

Comment: I don't know why but I had to add quotes it worked. test_db=# \i 'C:/Users/paude/Downloads/event_logic.dump'

Answer (score 77):

That worked for me:

```
sudo -u postgres psql db_name < 'file_path'
```

Comment: Always gave Error for all tables after import postgres DB : Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint. Any solution?

Comment: Are you sure your records have unique keys? Maybe you already have records with the same keys in the database?

Answer (score 70):

I'm not sure if this works for the OP's situation, but I found that running the following command in the interactive console was the most flexible solution for me:

```
\i 'path/to/file.sql'
```

Just make sure you're already connected to the correct database. This command executes all of the SQL commands in the specified file.

Comment: This solution worked for me while the most voted solution yielded "stdin is not a tty" error.

Comment: Just what I was looking for - a way to execute the script from inside the `psql` command line. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for this one. Should be included in the right answer.

Comment: this is correct, do not use back-slashes in the path in windows!

Comment: also for Windows, you need double-forward slashes

Comment: This repeats a three years old answer of @ArranUbels.

Answer (score 58):

Works pretty well, in command line, all arguments are required, -W is for password

```
psql -h localhost -U user -W -d database_name -f path/to/file.sql
```

Comment: After several tries this solution worked for me, pointing all the information necessary to execute the job: where to, database name, user, password and of course the file.

Answer (score 29):

Just for funsies, if your dump is compressed you can do something like

`gunzip -c filename.gz | psql dbname`

As Jacob mentioned, the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/backup.html) describe all this quite well.

Answer (score 21):

I tried many different solutions for restoring my postgres backup. I ran into permission denied problems on MacOS, no solutions seemed to work.

Here's how I got it to work:

Postgres comes with Pgadmin4. If you use macOS you can press `CMD`+`SPACE` and type `pgadmin4` to run it. This will open up a browser tab in chrome.

> If you run into errors getting pgadmin4 to work, try `killall pgAdmin4` in your terminal, then try again.

---

## Steps to getting pgadmin4 + backup/restore

### 1. Create the backup

Do this by rightclicking the database -> "backup"

[image]

### 2. Give the file a name.

Like `test12345`. Click backup. This creates a binary file dump, it's not in a `.sql` format

[image]

### 3. See where it downloaded

There should be a popup at the bottomright of your screen. Click the "more details" page to see where your backup downloaded to

[image]

### 4. Find the location of downloaded file

In this case, it's `/users/vincenttang`

[image]

### 5. Restore the backup from pgadmin

Assuming you did steps 1 to 4 correctly, you'll have a restore binary file. There might come a time your coworker wants to use your restore file on their local machine. Have said person go to pgadmin and restore

Do this by rightclicking the database -> "restore"

[image]

### 6. Select file finder

Make sure to select the file location manually, DO NOT drag and drop a file onto the uploader fields in pgadmin. Because you will run into error permissions. Instead, find the file you just created:

[image]

### 7. Find said file

You might have to change the filter at bottomright to "All files". Find the file thereafter, from step 4. Now hit the bottomright "Select" button to confirm

[image]

### 8. Restore said file

You'll see this page again, with the location of the file selected. Go ahead and restore it

[image]

### 9. Success

If all is good, the bottom right should popup an indicator showing a successful restore. You can navigate over to your tables to see if the data has been restored propery on each table.

### 10. If it wasn't successful:

Should step 9 fail, try deleting your old public schema on your database. Go to "Query Tool"

[image]

Execute this code block:

```
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE; CREATE SCHEMA public;
```

[image]

Now try steps 5 to 9 again, it should work out

## Summary

This is how I had to backup/restore my backup on Postgres, when I had error permission issues and could not log in as a superuser. Or set credentials for read/write using `chmod` for folders. This workflow works for a binary file dump default of "Custom" from pgadmin. I assume `.sql` is the same way, but I have not yet tested that

Comment: that's is not a good solution for large database files.

Answer (score 20):

make sure the database you want to import to is created, then you can import the dump with

```
sudo -u postgres -i psql testdatabase < db-structure.sql
```

If you want to overwrite the whole database, first drop the database

```
# be sure you drop the right database !!!
#sudo -u postgres -i psql -c "drop database testdatabase;"
```

and then recreate it with

```
sudo -u postgres -i psql -c "create database testdatabase;"
```

Comment: What's the functionality of `-i` option in this command?

Comment: see `man sudo` which ist the same as `--login`

Answer (score 18):

Follow the steps:

1. Go to the psql shell
2. `\c db_name`
3. `\i path_of_dump`  [eg:-C:/db_name.pgsql]

Answer (score 10):

I use:

```
cat /home/path/to/dump/file | psql -h localhost -U <user_name> -d <db_name>
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using a file with `.dump` extension use:

`pg_restore -h hostname -d dbname -U username filename.dump`

Answer (score 9):

I used this

```
psql -d dbName -U username -f /home/sample.sql
```

Answer (score 7):

I noticed that many examples are overcomplicated for localhost where just postgres user without password exist in many cases:

```
psql -d db_name -f dump.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in pgadmin3. Drop the schema(s) that your dump contains. Then right-click on the database and choose Restore. Then you can browse for the dump file.

Comment: But the 'restore' button is not click-able even after selecting the .sql file.  This software seems to want some other kind of file - one with *.backup format.  Clicking 'help' on that import-box refers to pg_restore - "...a utility for restoring a PostgreSQL database from an archive created by pg_dump in one of the non-plain-text formats."  The sql file the OP refers to is a plain-text format.

Answer (score 3):

Postgresql12

from sql file:
pg_restore -d database < file.sql

from custom format file:
pg_restore -Fc database < file.dump

Answer (score 1):

If you're on mac, quick one would be:

`sudo -u username psql database < /link/to/backup.sql`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```bash
psql -U <username> -d <database_name> < dump_file.sql
```

- `<username>`: Replace this with the username of the PostgreSQL user you want to connect as.
- `<database_name>`: Replace this with the name of the target database where you want to restore the SQL dump.
- `<dump_file.sql>`: Replace this with the path to the SQL dump file that you want to restore into the specified database. If the file is in the current directory, you can directly provide the filename (e.g., `my_dump.sql`). If it's in another directory, provide the full path (e.g., `/path/to/dump_name.sql`).

This command can be used either on the host machine (when PostgreSQL is installed locally) or inside a Docker container (using `docker exec` to run the `psql` command inside the container).

Answer (score 0):

I had more than 100MB data, therefore  I could not restore database using Pgadmin4.

I used simply postgres client, and write below command.

postgres@khan:/$  **pg_restore -d database_name  /home/khan/Downloads/dump.sql**

It worked fine and took few seconds.You can see below link for more information.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/app-pgrestore.html

Answer (score 0):

Either do this way

```
pg_restore --dbname=DB_NAME --verbose 2023-05-09T221119Z_pgdump
```

OR

```
psql fawkes_development < 2023-05-09T221119Z_pgdump
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`sudo -u postgres psql salesdb < "db (1).sql" -W`

- salesdb -> database name
- db (1).sql -> SQL file path

Answer (score 0):

If you have a binary dump in a file then you can restore it with:

```
pg_restore -f <filename>
```