# Starting My Ruby on Rails application - How to fill database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm tying to install my ruby on rails application on a new Server.

In the folder db theres is my schema.rb file.

But my problem ist how to run the schema.rb file to run the sql statements?

Comment: `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate` .... then `rake db:seed` if you have anything in the _seeds_ file

Comment: `rake db:schema:load`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

- `rake db:create` to create your DB (you do this only once)
- `rake db:migrate` to migrate your BD (do this the first time and every time you want to apply changes, like removing a column)

And

- `rake db:seed` to populate your DB, if you have something in you `seeds.rb` file

Comment: Yeah, I'm on a phone and I was scrolling. Removed downvote. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for fast answering, I only have copied the project folder to the new server. then I have to run rake db:create? so the shema will be createt on mysql server right?

at the moment there ar no data to migrate.

Comment: @NickM No problem :)
@Felix Just do `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`. Migrate is not about data (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

Answer (score 1):

The schema file doesn't populate the data, rather it shows the structure of the database. You'll have to run:

rake:db:create 
rake:db:migrate

on the new server and then create a dump of the data you wish to import to the new database. Then import the data. Both of these processes can differ widely depending on what kind of database you're using.

For MySQL:
[Export and Import all MySQL databases at one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497869/export-and-import-all-mysql-databases-at-one-time)

For PostgreSQL:
[import sql dump into postgresql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842393/import-sql-dump-into-postgresql-database)