# Loading SQL Server table dump into Postgresql DB?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, migration

Right now, I have been provided with a database dump of a SQL Server table and I need to load into a postgresql. Are there any good tools to convert the file and then load it? I have already tried pgloader. However, this returns me some really bad coding errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842393/import-sql-dump-into-postgresql-database?rq=1

Comment: More details about how the dump was performed are needed. Is this just csv data? An MDF? A .bak? SQL Insert statements? Excel?